# How to make shortcuts in git bash?

Tags: bash, shortcut, cd

for work I often have to access files that are far away in my tree and I wanted to know how/if I could configure git bash so that when I enter a command (let's call it "shortcut"), git does "cd Documents/.../.../.../FolderOfMyChoice".
It is only to save a little time. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: try defining an [alias](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-bash-aliases/).

Comment: Thank you very much definitely what I was looking for !

Comment: [`CDPATH`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Variables.html). See [`cd`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-cd)

Comment: Note: git-bash has nothing to do with Git except that Windows Git comes with it. (It's just a port *of* bash *to* Windows.)

Answer (score 0):

I find the `cdable_vars` bash option very convenient for fast directory access. If you enable it you can use a bash variable name as your `cd` destination:

```sh
shopt -s cdable_vars
fomc="~/Documents/FolderOfMyChoice"
```

And then:

```sh
cd fomc
```

Of course you will have to maintain a set of bash variables for your various favorite destinations, for instance in your `~/.bashrc` or a file sourced by your `~/.bashrc`. You can also define bash functions in your `~/.bashrc` to simplify all this. I have a `save [SHORTCUT]` function that, when called in a directory, defines a variable with the same name as the directory and which value is its full path. It also adds (or updates) this definition in a `~/.dirs` file that I source from my `~/.bashrc`. The function takes an optional argument in case I want to use another shortcut than the directory name. I also have a `delete [SHORTCUT]` function that unsets one of these variables and removes its definition from `~/.dirs`. Example of implementation (adapt to your own needs):

```sh
$ cat ~/.bashrc
...
shopt -s cdable_vars
dirsfile=~/.dirs
if [ -f "$dirsfile" ]; then
  source "$dirsfile"
fi

mySave () {
  d=$(pwd)
  b=$(basename "$d")
  s="${1:-$b}"

  [ "$s" = "/" ] && return
  [ -f "$dirsfile" ] || touch "$dirsfile"
  grep -q "^$s=" "$dirsfile" && sed -i "/^$s=/d" "$dirsfile"
  printf '%s="%s"\n' "$s" "$d" >> "$dirsfile"
  declare -ng tmp="$s"
  tmp="$d"
}

myDelete () {
  d=$(pwd)
  b=$(basename "$d")
  s="${1:-$b}"
  
  [ "$s" = "/" ] && return
  [ -f "$dirsfile" ] && sed -i "/^$s=/d" "$dirsfile"
  declare -ng tmp="$s"
  unset tmp
}
```

And then:

```sh
[/homes/doe/jhsdc] pwd
/homes/doe/jhsdc
[/homes/doe/jhsdc] mySave
[/homes/doe/jhsdc] cd /tmp
[/tmp] mySave foo
[/tmp] cd jhsdc
[/homes/doe/jhsdc] cd foo
[/tmp] myDelete jhsdc
[/tmp] cd jhsdc
bash: cd: jhsdc: No such file or directory
```